# Can I use the Spotify recommendation intelligence in an app?

Tags: api, spotify, recommendation-engine

On the Spotify dashboard an user has a great experience through the recommended artist and songs. I would like to use this intelligence in an app we plan to develop for a big Dutch based podium. So the app can give a list of concerts playing at the poppodium which the user might be interested in.

Can I get this recommended artist data, based on the user's history, through the Spotify API?

Answer (score 2):

The Spotify API now provides recommendations:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-recommendations/

> Recommendations are generated based on the available information for a
> given seed entity and matched against similar artists and tracks. If
> there is sufficient information about the provided seeds, a list of
> tracks will be returned together with pool size details.
>
> For artists and tracks that are very new or obscure there might not be
> enough data to generate a list of tracks.

There are a bunch of parameters that can be configured for fine-tuning the recommendation: key, genre, loudness, energy, instrumentalness, popularity, speechiness, danceability, key ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spotify's Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) endpoints to fetch these data:

1. The [Get a User’s Top Artists and Tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks/) endpoint will give you artists and tracks based on user's listening history. You can also use the [Get Current User’s Recently Played Tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-personalization-endpoints/get-recently-played/), which will give you up to 50 recently played tracks.
2. Use the artists and tracks you just get and use them as seeds for the [Get Recommendations Based on Seeds](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-recommendations/) endpoint. This endpoint will only return tracks. If you want to get artists based on other artists there is the [Get an Artist’s Related Artists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-related-artists/) endpoint that you can use.

As you see, combining multiple endpoints will get you covered. Just make sure you read the [Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) before. You are going to need the user to authenticate in order to get user's data.

Note: When the question was first posted (July 2013), Spotify's Web API didn't exist. The question referred to a now defunct Spotify Apps API which didn't provide a way to generate recommendations based on listening history.

Comment: This looks no longer true, and you can say it much better than me providing you work at Spotify :)